# How to show the progressbar while playing audio file in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I have an audio file in the server, so I am able to play the audio file with the url. Below is the code. How can I show the progress bar while playing the audio file?

```
-(void)playselectedsong{
    AVPlayer *player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an AVAsset with the URL and then fetch the duration of the AVAsset created with the URL.

```
AVAsset *audio = [AVAsset assetWithURL:]; // create an audio instance.
float duration = CMTimeGetSeconds([audio currentTime]); // gives the seconds of audio file.

AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: audio]; // create a player item.

AVPlayer *avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item]; // initialise the AVPlayer with the AVPlayerItem.

[avPlayer play]; // play the AVPlayer
```

Then you can design progress bar which will update every seconds after playing the audio file.

```
UIProgressView *myProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
```

invoke an update method after every second.

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(methodToUpdateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Then in "methodToUpdateProgress" update the progress bar.

```
[myProgressView setProgress:someFloat animated:YES];
```